# Is there a way to delete a webpart using powershell but not using title property in the condition?

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, properties, title

I've created a powershell script to delete a webpart, It is working but is there another way to delete a webpart without using the title property in the condition?

I have a scenario wherein a certain user changed the title of the webpart so if the tool is run on that site it will not delete the webpart because the title has been changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you already have all the code.

Then, you need to search your Web Part by checking :

```
$webpartmanager.WebParts[0].GetType().Name
```

".GetType().Name" 'll give you the name of your WebPart, not his title.